# Sorting column in vb.net datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have added a column to an existing vb.net datagridview

```
    Dim col = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    col.DataPropertyName = "wincent"
    col.Name = "winpct"
    col.HeaderText = "Win%"
    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
```

the added column is not sortable, the rest of the columns in the gridview are. How can I make the added column sortable?

In response to the question, I omitted to make clear the datagridview is bound thus

```
        Dim myconnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = connectionmodule.Makeconnection
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from todaysturfraces", myconnection)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "todaysturfraces")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("todaysturfraces")
    DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
```

Apologies for the ommission

Comment: Did you perhaps fail to mention that the original columns are bound through a datasource and this one is not? That's the only way I could reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes I did. Apologies for the omission

Comment: No problem, so you're going to want to add a column to your `todaysturfraces` table and populate it by iterating the rows. But depending on what this information is derived from, it could be as easy as performing the calculations in the query itself. (I'm assuming you added a column and are looping through the rows and calculating a percent from a couple of columns).

Comment: @charles, Thank you for your help. I shall perform the calculation in the query as you suggest then store it . And then upon retrieval there is no need for a column to be added programmatically. Thank you. If you post your suggestion as an answer I shall mark it as such.

Comment: OK, but just want to get clarification on the `"then store it"` part. You're not planning on storing the result in your actual database table are you? It's not necessary and not advisable. Just perform it in the SELECT statement that you send to the DataAdapter and it will appear in your dataset table.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was going to store it, but now I learn there is no need. Even better. Thanks again. My Saturday is getting better and better - I hope the same is true of yours!